Measure recall or false negatives rate in a very unbalanced data set
We want to measure recall (or the false negative rate) for our machine learning model. The problem is that the Positive Case only exists in <0.1% of all cases and we can't afford to annotate the amount of data needed for a proper evaluation.
Measuring precision is no problem.
Are there any methods for handling such data sets?
We already tried sampling methods for increasing the rate of positives in our data which we annotate. However this creates a significant bias to the recall evaluation which is not wanted by our employer.
Due to data protection rules, we can't outsource the annotation process.

You seem to have the same kind of problem as is discussed in the King & Zeng paper mentioned in a few answers here.
